# How to open pdf file in external app or in webview size is greater than 25mb

Tags: android, pdf, webview

hello i want to show pdf file in webview or in external app. 
1) i use this url
`https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url= +pdfurl` , but google says "Whoops There was a problen while previewing document" 
2) if i use intent to open the url in external app then they didnot load the file in external app. 
3) if i use the intent to open the url in browser then its start downloading the pdf file.

```
Intent ii=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    ii.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pdf),"text/html");
    try {
        startActivity(ii);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(QuranPara.this, "NO Pdf Viewer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

here is the complete url https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=www.elibrary.alnoorpk.com/PDF%20Books/Lafzi_aur_bamahawrah_terjma_2015/Para%201%20(Lafzi%20aur%20Bamuhawra%20Tarjma).pdf

check the image [image: check the error]

Comment: Have you already downloaded that image in external storage or that PDFs are already in assets folder?

Comment: my pdf is in server, i open it from url but didnot work,

Comment: If your pdf are open to reading and no copyright act applicable to them then for all the audience, you can provide functionality for download the pdf on the devices.

Comment: It would help if you used the correct MIME type. The MIME type of a PDF file is not `text/html`. The MIME type of a PDF is `application/pdf`.

Comment: @CommonsWare i also done this but the app didnot open the file in external app it just show the loading window

Answer (score 2):

To show it in WebView try something like this

```
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
    webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

To show it in browser try something like this

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: thanks for respone. please open my url, it will gives you an error. Your pdf file is small thats why its open.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are in assets first copy them to the external storage. Hope that you have handled permission flow.

Try the following code for **offline**

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"pdfName.pdf");//Pdf file path
            if (pdfFile.exists()) //Checking for the file is exist or not
            {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
                Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                objIntent.setFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(objIntent);//Staring the pdf viewer
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The file not exists! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Try the following for the **webview** option if you choose that

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "online pdf link";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

But Remember if you use google docs for viewing the pdf or any other doc, google docs may throw you the error stating

`You've reached the bandwidth limit for viewing or downloading files that aren't in Google Docs format..... So doesn't seem reliable`

So, **be cautious** with google doc viewing