# android cannot display PDF (name.pdf is of invalid format)

Tags: android, pdf, android-volley

I'm downloading a file using volley and I'm not able to open it, it shows this:

> cannot display PDF (name.pdf is of invalid format)

Also mention that service returns an 11kb byte[] and debugging, I'm receiving an 16kb response. The code I'm using is:

```
InputStreamVolleyRequest request = new InputStreamVolleyRequest(Request.Method.POST, uri,
            new Response.Listener<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(byte[] response) {                        
                    try {
                        if (response!=null) {

                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>22){
                                requestPermissions(new String[] {"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE","android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"}, 1);
                            }

                            File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                            baseDir.mkdirs();
                            File carpeta = new File(baseDir + nombre_carpeta);
                            carpeta.mkdirs();
                            File file = new File(baseDir, documento.NombreFichero.replace("\\","/"));
                            try {
                                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                                bos.write(response);
                                bos.flush();
                                bos.close();
                                Log.d("NEWFILE", file.getAbsolutePath());
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Descarga completa.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("KEY_ERROR", "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } ,new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, (HashMap<String, String>) params);

    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack());
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793399/5885018

Comment: @statosdotcom not really, but thanks

Answer (score 2):

Finally I send the response as string and then decode it with **android.util.Base64** . This is the code:

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uri, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                baseDir.mkdirs();
                File carpeta = new File(baseDir + nombre_carpeta);
                carpeta.mkdirs();
                File file = new File(baseDir, documento.NombreFichero.replace("\\","/"));
                BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] respuesta = android.util.Base64.decode(response.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);

                fos.write(respuesta);

                fos.flush();

                fos.close();
                output.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a programming problem. I suggest that in your emulator or device, you install a pdf reader ([Google PDF Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.pdfviewer&hl=pt_BR)).

If you are using an emulator, it may be necessary for you to use a version that has Google Play already installed. And then you can install the pdf reader.

Comment: I uploaded to drive and tried to open it and downloading to my computer, but the pdf can't be read

Comment: @Juan have you checked what you retrieve instead?

Comment: @mkl when the service was sending byte[], I received base64. But had problems decoding (it was decoded, but it wrote literla Base64 at file), so now I send it as string UTF_8 and get its bytes to byte[]. It works fine with .txt files. Thanks

Comment: @Juan *"so now I send it as string UTF_8 and get its bytes to byte[]. It works fine with .txt files."* - Well, that explains it. Sending a PDF as UTF-8 encoded string is very likely to damage it. UTF-8 is a *text* encoding, so it makes sense that *It works fine with .txt files* but PDF is a *binary format*, and treating binaries like text always has good chances of damaging the binary data.

Comment: @mkl but sending as byte[], I do receive a Base64 code and even if I decode it, it writes the Base64 code. What do I have to do to?

Comment: @Juan *"even if I decode it, it writes the Base64 code"* - then your *base64 decoding code* has a bug because the output of Base64 decoding with non-empty input never is identical to the input. Or if you merely mean that the output also is Base64 encoded but not identical to the input, probably the data for some weird reason is base64 encoded twice, so you'd have to either reduce the encoding code to a single encoding run or also decode multiple times. But you neither show the base64 decoding code nor do you share the encoded data, so we can merely guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, finally I solved like my response